# Javafx Task for Bluetooth data reciever

Tags: javafx-8, bluecove

I am creating javafx application where I have this case that I need to listen for data sent over Bluetooth.
I have one fxml window on which I need to initialize Bluetooth and start listening from data.

Following is my Code for fxml controller:

```
//all imports 

public class NewBarcodeInvoicePaneController  implements Initializable{
    private BluetoothController bc;

    public BluetoothController getBc() {
        return bc;
    }    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            bc = new BluetoothController();
            new Thread(bc).start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

And  BluetoothController is task where I initialize bluettoth and listen to the data

```
public class BluetoothController extends Task<Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        LocalDevice local = null;
        StreamConnectionNotifier notifier;
        StreamConnection connection = null;

        // setup the server to listen for connection
        try {
            local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            try {
                local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
            } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
            }

            UUID uuid = new UUID(80087355); // "04c6093b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
            String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid.toString() + ";name=RemoteBluetooth";
            notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            System.err.println("THIS IS HAPENING");
            connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();
            System.err.println("HAPENING???????????????????????????");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String lineRead = bReader.readLine();
            connection.close();
            inputStream.close();
            notifier.close();
            local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.NOT_DISCOVERABLE);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(lineRead);
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
            array.stream().map((o) -> (String) o).forEach((stringObj) -> {
                System.out.println(stringObj);
            });
            System.out.println("AFTER DATA RECIEVED");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

It Works fine if I send data over bluetooth and blocking call to notifier.acceptAndOpen() is unblocked.
My problem is when we do not pass any data and I just want to close the window I opened..
It still have blocking call open with extra thread by the task.
I tried to cancel BluetoothController task in Main controller where I open this window like following

```
 private void openNewBarcodeInvoicePane(ActionEvent ae) {
        //following are custom classes to open windows from fxml and getting controller back for further manipulation
        PostoryModalWindow modalWindow = new PostoryModalWindow();
        modalWindow.openNewModalPaneWithParent("New Invoice", "fxml/newbarcodeinvoicepane.fxml", ae);
        //getting controller object 
        NewBarcodeInvoicePaneController controller = (NewBarcodeInvoicePaneController) modalWindow.getDswFromController();
        controller.getWindowStage().showAndWait();
        BluetoothController bc = controller.getBc();
        if(bc != null){
            System.err.println("CANCELLING");
            bc.cancel(true);
        }        
    }
```

But it doesn't throw InterrupttedExeption (In which I might have Choice to close Bluetooth thread) and after research I found that waiting on Socket doesn't work on interrupt.

Any help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got Solution After Some Research.
I just added new task to call `notifier.acceptAndOpen();`
And added method to close Bluetooth notifier.

```
public class BluetoothController extends Task<Void> {
    private final ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     public ObservableList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    StreamConnectionNotifier notifier;

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        try {
            BluetoothConnectionTask bct = new BluetoothConnectionTask(items);
            new Thread(bct).start();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            notifier = bct.getNotifier();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void cancelandExit() {
        try {
            if (notifier != null) {
                notifier.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is new task for blocking call

```
public class BluetoothConnectionTask extends Task<Void>{
    private StreamConnectionNotifier notifier;
    private StreamConnection connection;
    private ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public StreamConnection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public StreamConnectionNotifier getNotifier() {
        return notifier;
    }


    public BluetoothConnectionTask(ObservableList<Item> is){
        items = is;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        try {
            LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            try {
                local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
            } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
            }

            UUID uuid = new UUID(80087355); // "04c6093b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
            String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid.toString() + ";name=RemoteBluetooth";
            notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String lineRead = bReader.readLine();
            connection.close();
            inputStream.close();
            notifier.close(); 
            LocalDevice  local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.NOT_DISCOVERABLE);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(lineRead);
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
            ItemDAO idao = new ItemDAO();
            array.stream().map((o) -> (String) o).forEach((stringObj) -> {
                String barcode = (String) stringObj;
                Item i = idao.getItemByBarCode(barcode);
                System.err.println("Adding Item "+i.getName());
                items.add(i);
            });
            System.out.println("AFTER DATA RECIEVED");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now for cancelling closing my bluetooth thread I am calling `cancelandExit()` after window is closed.